# Connection between $J_k= \sum_{n=1}^k e^{-n}=\frac{1-e^{-k}}{e-1} $ and $ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^x} ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, analytic-continuation

Consider the geometric series$$J_k= \sum_{n=1}^k e^{-n}=\frac{1-e^{-k}}{e-1} $$

I'm wondering if this has any connection with:

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^x}. $$

$J_k$ can be interpreted as adding up y-values on the curve $y=e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$ for $x=e^{-1/n}$ in the same way that $H_k$ can be interpreted as adding up y-values on the curve $y=1/x$ for $x=n\ge1.$

Now the Harmonic numbers, $H_k$ are closely related to the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}.$

Might there be a close relationship between $J_k$ and $f(x)?$

> Please help me understand why or why not?

Comment: The OP already asked 10 questions about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^x}$.

Comment: Repeatedly asking about a strange function without really caring about the answers (as shown in your above post, not even referencing any previous answer) is not ok.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I can ask genuine questions until my understanding and curiosity is satisfied. I care about ALL  answers I receive on this platform and do my best to understand them.

Comment: To study the asymptotics as $x\to 0$ we can replace the sum by an integral which gives $i(x) = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n^{x}}\,dn \simeq \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-n^{x}}\,dn= \frac {1}{x} \Gamma(\frac{1}{x})=\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{x})$. For $x\to 0$ we find from Stirling's formula: $i(x) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi /x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}} x^{-\frac{1}{x}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few observations:

---

**(1)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}=\frac{1}{e-1}$

**(2)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{-n}\right)^s=\frac{1}{e^s-1}$

**(3)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\vartheta _3\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)-1\right)$

---

Now consider the function $f(x)$ defined in formula (3) below and the related function $F(s)$ defined in formula (4) below.

---

**(3)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)$

**(4)** $\quad F(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$

---

Setting $a(n)=1$ yields the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ as illustrated in formula (5) below, and setting $a(n)=e^{-n}$ yields the PolyLog function $\text{Li}_s\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$ as illustrated in formula (6) below.

---

**(5)** $\quad\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^s}=\zeta(s),\quad \Re(s)>1$

**(6)** $\quad\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{e^{-n}}{n^s}=\text{Li}_s\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$

---

Note formula (5) above diverges at $s=1$ as $N\to\infty$ (since the Harmonic series diverges), but setting $s=1$ in formula (6) above yields the following.

---

**(7)** $\quad\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{-n}}{n}=\text{Li}_1\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=-\log \left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)$

---

The partial sums associated with formulas (5) and (6) at $s=1$ are as follows where $\Phi()$ is the [Lerch transcendent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html).

---

**(8)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}=H_N$

**(9)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{-n}}{n}=-\log \left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)-e^{-N-1} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{e},1,N+1\right)$

Comment: I think (2) isn't right

Comment: @geocalc33 I mixed x and s. I believe formula (2) is now correct (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28E%5E-n%29%5Es+%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D).